# jQuery ajax beforeSend interfering with .done()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In a website I have several ajax-parts that are loaded by events, mostly clicks. To inform the visitor a loading partial is shown. This works nice most of the time, but sometimes the ajax call is receiving the respons so quick it interferes with the beforeSend.

My typical structure looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.handler', function() { 
  var target = $(this).attr('data-targetElement');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax.php?someParameter=hasValue',
    beforeSend: showLoading(target)
  })
  .done(function(response) { 
    console.log('Hi there, I\'m done!');
    $('#' + target).html(response);
  });
});

// This is in a function because it's used by all ajax-calls
function showLoading(target) { 
  $('#' + target).html('My loading message');
}
```

The problem is, when I'm inspecting console messages, that the loading message is still shown even though the .done() was reached, because `Hi there, I'm done!` is shown.

So it looks beforeSend doesn't seem to have reached a completed state or something like that causing it to 'freeze', because the content in the targetElement is not updated with the response for the ajax-call.

I'm not sure how to solve to this. Any suggestions?

Update,
Sorry for the typo, I just typed the exemplary code in here...

Comment: have you tried to `console.log()` the `showLoading()` function as well to make sure they are called in the order you think they are?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?,  create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Is expected result a delay between `beforeSend`  message display , `.done()` message display ?

Comment: Right know, ignoring the syntax error in the `$.ajax()` options..., `showLoading()` is called before `$.ajax()` is called

Comment: I wasn't aware of that Andreas. You were correct to ignore the syntax error (typed it in here, as an example of what my code looks like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At first, you need to fix all syntax errors in your code.
   Remove `;` in the middle of the statement.

   ```
   $.ajax({
     beforeSend: showLoading(target);
     //                             ^ SYNTAX ERROR
   })
   ```
2. When you write `showLoading(target)` you call the `showLoading()` function immediately.

   If you need to set pass it as a callback with parameters, you need to pass a function, that returns your callback.

   ```
   beforeSend: function() {
       showLoading(target);
   }
   ```

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: I believe putting it inside a function() {} does the trick. I'll keep an eye on it for now. The syntax error was made by mistake. I started typing out the main idea of how my ajax calls are handled. It was exemplary, but with an error ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing syntax error semicolon `;` at close of `beforeSend` , utilizing `var target = $(this).data('targetelement');` for `target` variable

```
$(document).on('click', '.handler', function() { 
  var target = $(this).data('targetelement');
  console.log(target)
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/echo/html/',
    beforeSend: function() {showLoading(target)},
    data:{html:"Hi there, I\'m done!"}
  })
  .done(function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
    $('#' + target).html(response);
  });
});

// This is in a function because it's used by all ajax-calls
function showLoading(target) { 
  $('#' + target).html('My loading message');
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4xp1aag8/1/

Comment: With this syntax error the ajax call won't be triggered at all

Comment: So a syntax error won't stop the execution of a script? And if `;` is the only problem why you've changed `beforeSend: ...`?

Comment: @Andreas Initially misread , misinterpreted comment . _"is the only problem why you've changed beforeSend: ...? "_ No, substituted `.data("targetelement")` for `$(this).attr('data-targetElement');`

Comment: And the explanation for the changed `beforeSend`? "Hidden" changes won't help to clarify why it now works as intended

Comment: _"And the explanation for the changed beforeSend? "Hidden" changes won't help to clarify why it now works as intended"_  `;` following `beforeSend` is syntax error , added to updated post above.

Comment: As you don't know what I mean I think you've just copy&pasted the code from another answer... `showLoading(target)` is wrapped in an anonymous function. Why?!

Comment: @Andreas _"As you don't know what I mean I think you've just copy&pasted the code from another answer..."_ Really ? Do not do any _"copy&pasted"_ from any other answer , here. Which answer ? No other viewer of Question capable of  interpreting syntax error ? Be careful with accusations cannot prove . _"showLoading(target) is wrapped in an anonymous function. Why?!"_ Does not have to be wrapped in anonymous function http://jsfiddle.net/4xp1aag8/2/

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've accepted an answer, +1. Have a nice day